# syntax of "is" operator in python

Tags: python

```
list = ['xy', 'yz', '=', '1', 'in', '>', 't']

for value in list:
   if value is '0' or '1':
      Zustand = value
      print("Zustand:", Zustand)
```

The if loop should check if the value of list is 0 or 1. Why does it print every value? I also tried the "==" operator.

Comment: because `'1'` is always True.

Comment: `if value == '0' or value == '1':`

Comment: Don't use `is` to compare values

Comment: Please [read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is) for `is`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if value is '0' or '1':
```

this is evaluated as

```
if (value is '0') or ('1'):
```

which is always true. try

```
if value is '0' or value is '1':
```

Comment: The OP should also not be using `is` here; it's implementation-dependent whether `value` refers to the same object that the literal `'0'` refers to.

Comment: yes, this is not how `is`  be used. I just used as OP seems to use it. this is a clear case to use `==`. `value in ['0', '1']` can be used here.